# ./mvnw clean install can not be built

Tags: spring-boot

I tried to build spring-boot from source and ran the command described at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

```
./mvnw clean install
```

Then, it became FAILURE on the way of building Spring Boot Maven Plugin as follows.

```
[INFO] Spring Boot Dependencies ........................... SUCCESS [  6.237 s]
[INFO] Spring Boot Parent ................................. SUCCESS [04:36 min]
[INFO] Spring Boot Tools .................................. SUCCESS [  0.984 s]
[INFO] Spring Boot Configuration Metadata ................. SUCCESS [01:10 min]
[INFO] Spring Boot Configuration Processor ................ SUCCESS [  7.661 s]
[INFO] Spring Boot Loader ................................. SUCCESS [02:39 min]
[INFO] Spring Boot Loader Tools ........................... SUCCESS [ 47.458 s]
[INFO] Spring Boot Maven Plugin ........................... FAILURE [03:43 min]
[INFO] Spring Boot Gradle Plugin .......................... SKIPPED
```

I'd like to SUCCESS all and complete the build.

The execution environment is as follows.

- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
- CPU: 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5
- Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- JAVA Version: java version "1.8.0_40" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
- Maven: Apache Maven 3.1.1 (0728685237757ffbf44136acec0402957f723d9a; 2013-09-18 00:22:22+0900)

Comment: Are there no errors before or after the output you posted?

Comment: can you please try with **./mvnw clean install -e or ./mvnw clean install -X ** to show more error stack trace?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ran the following command next.

./mvnw clean install -e

Then another error occurred.

Comment: As the text became longer, I copied the stack trace into the Answer column.